How to convert symbols like x1 to $x_1$, but handle differentials like dH1 to $dH_1$ in Mathematica?
I need help with a symbol transformation in Mathematica. I want to convert symbols such as x1 to Subscript[x, 1], but I need to handle differentials (as simple symbols not operators) differently. For example, dH1 should become Subscript[dH, 1], not Subscript[d, Subscript[H, 1]].
Is there a way to achieve this transformation correctly without nesting subscripts for symbols that represent differentials?
Thanks in advance!

You can do the following:
 SetAttributes[MySubscriptForm, Listable];
 MySubscriptForm[s_Symbol] /; SameQ[Attributes[s], {}] && 
 StringLength@ToString@s > 1 := 
 Module[{gat, test1, test2},
 gat = GatherBy[Characters[ToString[s]], LetterQ];
 test1 = ContainsAny[Flatten@gat, {"E", "I", "\[ImaginaryI]", "π", "K", "C"}];
 test2 = MatchQ[Flatten@gat, {__?LetterQ}];
 If[ContainsOnly[{test1, test2}, {False}] === False, s, 
 Subscript["" <> #1, Sequence @@ ("" <> #2)] & @@ gat] /.      
 str_String :> ToExpression[str]]

Testing MySubscriptForm:
MySubscriptForm[{dH1, dt, dξ, k1, k2, l2, x1, x2}] // TeXForm


$\left\{\text{dH}_1,\text{dt},\text{d$\xi $},k_1,k_2,l_2,x_1,x_2\right\}$

One of the tests in MySubscriptForm prevents you from using symbols that have some attribute, and in that case, converting to subscript format will not pass, as you can see in the following examples:
MySubscriptForm[{π1, E2, I3, I4}]


{π1, E2, I3, I4}

Finally, if you want to build a function that allows you to modify these types of symbols in complicated expressions, you can use the first modules of the SymbolToSubscript (by E. Chan-López & Jaime Manuel Cabrera) function and combine with MySubscriptForm.

Thanks for your answer! It seems to work very well!

You're welcome, I'm glad to help!
